# How to accelerate a Hibernate application startup?

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, tomcat

When I start a Java web app that uses Hibernate to connect to a Oracle DB it spends 20 minutes doing something like this

> [APPNAME] 12 Nov 2012 13:08:29.456  INFO TableMetadata:62 - table found: SCHEMANAME.TABLENAMEA

One of the problems is that it is finding tables from unnecessary schemas.

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is already set to `none`

I'm using Hibernate 3

Comment: If you see TableMetadata being used, then for certain something is running Hibernate's SchemaUpdate or SchemaValidation tool.

Comment: @SteveEbersole Is there any way to disable those tools?

Comment: Well you said you set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `none` which should so it.  You'll have to find out how they are being enabled and who is enabling them.  Could be that something is executing them directly too.  Hard to say without more detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Schema Validation in Spring 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160104/disable-schema-validation-in-spring-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the string TABLESPACENAME doesn't represent a schema (user) name? I've never seen table names prefixed with tabespace names in this way. Anyway, if that's the case then the system may either be querying ALL_TABLES instead of USER_TABLES, or you are connecting as a user with too many privileges (like SELECT ANY TABLE).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Oracle, I didn't know that a schema was different from a tablespace.

Comment: I know my user has too many permissions, but I can't change that right now. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: 20 minutes does seem like a long time -- do you know how many tables' metadata it is retrieving?

Comment: There are about 20 tables. The database is very slow.

Comment: 20 tables that you need the metadata for, or 20 that it is fetching the metadata for?

Comment: 20 that I'm fetching and I need, plus 15 that I'm fetching but I don't need.

Comment: If it's taking that long to pull the details of 35 tables then something's definitely wrong, but I'd be really surprised if it's purely a database issue. Something on the Hibernate side, and I'm afraid I can't help you with that.